# How to make a ng-change listener limited to a specific dom?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

In short: Need an AngularJS solution where the change-event callback for data/property changes in a model only works within a certain DOM and not the whole scope/template controller by a controller.

Detail: I have a template controlled by a controller. The properties of a model (there are lot of properties ) can be edited from different sections within that template. I need a smart but simple way to know from which section the model is being modified by the user, typically invoking different method for different section.

I know the lengthy solution of adding ng-change in each of the model-property input field, but instead can it be smarter by adding some custom ng-change/directive of a particular section container (div)? I tried adding a custom directive in a section that listens for change in that model, but that also fires when the model is modified outside of that section.

Here is the code excerpt :

```
<div class="profile" object-change-listener object="user" callback="didChangeProfile()">
        <label>First name:</label>
    <input type="text" ng-model="user.firstName">
    <br>
    <label>Last name:</label>
    <input type="text" ng-model="user.lastName">
    <br>
</div>
  <div class="settings" object-change-listener object="user" callback="didChangeSettings()">
    <p><b>Settings</b></p>
    <label>Fav Color:</label>
    <input type="text" ng-model="user.favColor">
    <br>    
    <label>Fav Number:</label>
    <input type="text" ng-model="user.favNumber">
  </div>
```

Here is the codepen to explain the scenario : http://codepen.io/tusharbhatta/pen/dXBLPG of what I'm trying to achieve, but both section's callback function fires, even if I change one section.

Appriciate any help or pointer.

Comment: why you don't use a $scope.$watch instead a directive for the changes in user object? with a $watch you have access to the entire user object, and you can put your logic there.

Comment: Because that doesn't give any clue about which UI section causes that change. I want to detect which UI section is responsible for the change in that object.